# Docker- docker file to create postgresql Image from postgresql-9.6.1.tar.gz tarball?

Tags: postgresql, docker

How to build postgresql-9.6 image from postgresql-9.6.1.tar.gz using dockerfile?

I tried to create below dockerfile to install postgresql-9.6 on ubuntu. But I am unable to make it a complete image?

`FROM ubuntu:16.04`
`RUN    apt-get update && \`
`apt-get install software-properties-common -y && \` 
`apt-get install wget && \`
`add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" && \` 
`wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - && \`
`apt-get update && \`
`apt-get install -y postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6`
`EXPOSE 5432`

So as an alternative I want to create image from tarball

Comment: Show the efforts that you have already tried and ask specific issues that you are facing

Comment: Pl. check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

The official [Postgres Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bef8f02d1fe2bb4547280ba609f19abd20230180/9.6/Dockerfile) does a build from source on Debian which should be largely portable to Ubuntu.

It will be easier to just use the `postgres:9.6` or `postgres:9.6.1` image as a seperate container to your application, rather than trying to manage a build heavy, monolithic container yourself.

Comment: The official docker postgres use alpine:3.5 as base image, but I want java image (custom image)  as my base image for  which ubuntu16.01 is base image

Comment: The alpine image is a seperate build, I thought I'd linked the other one...fixed

Comment: Thank you Matt, but I want to build a custom postgresql image. Any help will be very much appreciated